# How to log Celebrate validation errors to the console in Express.js?

Tags: express, logging, error-handling, joi

I have an Express.js app in which I'm trying to log the validation errors returned by [Celebrate](https://github.com/arb/celebrate) to the console so that I can analyze them with the logging service that I use (which is GCP's Cloud Logging).

I'm currently just using the error handling middleware provided by Celebrate as suggested in the documentation:

```js
// app.js

const { errors } = require('celebrate');

...

app.use(errors());

...
```

How can I extend the middleware (without re-implementing it) so that it also logs the validation errors to the console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to achieve this seems to be by defining another error middleware **before the Celebrate error middleware**, that checks whether the error is a Celebrate error (using the `isCelebrateError` method) and if so it logs it to the console:

```js
// app.js

const { errors, isCelebrateError } = require('celebrate');

...


// middleware to log Celebrate validation errors
app.use((err, req, res, next) => {
    if (isCelebrateError(err)) {
        console.error(err);
    }
    next(err);
});

// Celebrate middleware to return validation errors
app.use(errors());

...
```

It is important to include the logging middleware before Celebrate's `errors()` middleware since `errors()` returns a JSON response and no other middleware is run after it (you can check out the [Celebrate source code](https://github.com/arb/celebrate/blob/458bdc1a97384028b6c10069007af801ce4bd235/lib/celebrate.js#L179-L213) for the implementation details of `errors()`).